# Internet Explorer 11 displays error in app.js (3820,1) file vuejs app, works with other browser

Tags: vue.js

My vuejs app works with other browsers well, but in Internet Explorer 11 it just displays a blank page.

The Babel code is not converted. How can I fix that?

I have used Bootstrap and Google charts as plugins.

Comment: What errors do you get? Could you update the question with errors you get?

Comment: script error 1002 .When i go to the line number, it shows ansi regex.There is problem in ansi regex ? Its inside app.js (built file)

Comment: Please enrich your question with the error which IE says

Comment: IE just displays script error 1002 in app.js file.There is no other detail